# Page Access for anonymous user and with a specific group

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I have a page: `/events/`
(a) If the user is not logged in, i want him to see a login
-> Result: Page is `visible for all` + Login-Element on page (with: `hide on login`)
(b) If the user is in the usergroup `eventuser`, he should see an event-plugin on the page
-> Events-Plugin is on page (with group permission: `eventuser`)

Everything cool for those two guys.

But if the user is a normal logged-in user (without the group `eventuser`) the page `/events/` is empty.

How can i create a page which is accessible for anonymous users (to show a login) and is visible in the navigation for `eventuser`s but not for standard fe_users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two pages on the same level.

The first one is accessible for everyone (with "hide on login" set), the second one is accessible for the `eventuser` group only.
Create your login plugin on the publicly available page and set a redirect to the restricted page on successful login.

[image]

Create your event plugin on the access restricted page.

Now you need to set a redirect page for your other groups (or the other way around) after successful login, so all other groups, except `eventuser` will get redirected somewhere else. They won't see the events page at all.

[image]

[image]

hth

Comment: Thank you for this description. My problem was that the user visits my page over an external link: `/events/` - with this solution i have to rename the original page. 
But i think there is no other solution?

Comment: Maybe you find another way by changing the events page type to 'shortcut' (with mode 'first subpage') and a combination of access rights for the subpages (which have 'hide in menu' set). But if you want to hide the events page completely for all signed in users except the eventuser group users I think there's no other (easy) solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create two user group `eventuser` and `websiteuser`.

Now you can redirect user on specific page using redirect option in group configuration.

If user assign `websiteuser` gruop then you can redirect it's your site home page and `eventuser` group redirect to event page.

See below screenshot.
[image]